# What's wrong in my bootstrap navbar code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

My bootstrap navbar works perfectly fine, but if i switch to phone view in developer tools and click the expand button, it just doesn't expand.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Storyfactory</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed bg-primary" type="button" data-toggle="#hanshuber" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hanshuber">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="/user/2" class="mr-3"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/logout"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `toggle` and `target` data attributes are incorrect.

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hanshuber"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Storyfactory</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed bg-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hanshuber" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hanshuber">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="/user/2" class="mr-3"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```